# ListView Recycle mechanism

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I understood ListView Recycle mechanism very well from [How ListView's recycling mechanism works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945563/how-listviews-recycling-mechanism-works) but i don't understand one thing,

If i want to change height of list row then why it only works by setting height dynamically,

For example :

```
convertView.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(AbsListView.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,80));
```

If i define height of row layout in xml it does not change,  how it is related to recycle mechanism ?

It is not only for list row height i have seen many cases where attributes of xml does not work but changing them dynamically works well, but how ?

Comment: Can you provide some examples where `setting the attributes of xml` don't work? Also where you inflate that specific item's xml layout.

Comment: @user3249477 sorry it was my mistake i was trying to inflate layout in wrong way

Answer (score 1):

I understood, there was a small mistake i was trying to inflate listview layout using

```
convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null,false);
```

above code was the main reason, why attributes of xml were not working. Then i changed it to

```
convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, parent,false);
```

Now it is working as expected, sorry but recycle mechanism has nothing to do with xml, i lost there.